# Python regular expression regex that will find double consonants within a word

Tags: python, regex

I need a regex in python that will return and double characters within a word if they are consonants. I tried `((\w)\2)+|([^aeiou\s])`, however it will also grab `['o','o']` in the word `'flood'`. For example, I want to return `['p','p']` from the word `'happy'` but not `['o','o']` from `'food'`

Answer (score 1):

```
double_consonant = re.compile("([bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz])(\\1)", re.I)

double_consonant.search("flood")     # => "None"
double_consonant.search("adder")     # => <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(1, 3), match='dd'>
```

Comment: @MalikBrahimi: I have not yet found a clean method of doing that (`\w` includes digits and underscore). I supposed you could use `[b-df-hj-np-tv-xz]` but it's not really that much cleaner.

Comment: Is there not a class intersection operator for the desired combination of `[^aeiou]` and `\w`?

Comment: @MalikBrahimi: it would be nice, but I've never seen one!

Comment: Usually, we do `(?![aeiou])[a-z]`, but it is for English only.

Comment: I figured it out, you can use a lookahead regex, see below.

Answer (score 0):

```
results = re.findall(r'(?=[^aeiou])([a-z])\1', your_string):
```

Answer (score -1):

use this pattern

```
\b\w+([^aeiou])(\1)\w+\b
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/200)

Comment: @raysmith how about now, didn't realize you want to capture letters